# i need help, i need to write an array, put variabels with math.random and caculate the slants

Tags: java, arrays

the array is printing up zeros and only then numbers
and doesnt caculate the slants

i tried to switch the variabels and rewrite to coded loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class shishistimempire {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        System.out.println("enter the size of the array");
        i=s.nextInt();
        int[][] arr= new int[i][i];

        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++) {
            for(int n=0;n<arr.length; n++) {
                arr[j][n]= (int) (Math.random()*i+1);

            }
            for(int y=0;y<arr.length;y++) {
                for(int r=0;r<arr.length;r++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[y][r] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }




        }
        int am=0 , ar=0;
        for (int o=0; o<arr.length;o++) { 
            ar= ar+arr[o][o];
        }
        for(int h=0; h<arr.length;h++) {
            am=am+arr[i-1][i-1];
            i--;
        }
System.out.println("your main slant is" + am);
System.out.println("your second slant is" + ar);

    }}
```

---

```
enter the size of the array
4
1 1 4 3 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
1 1 4 3 
2 2 3 2 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
1 1 4 3 
2 2 3 2 
3 1 2 4 
0 0 0 0 
1 1 4 3 
2 2 3 2 
3 1 2 4 
4 3 2 2 
your main slant is7
your second slant is7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you did the same calculation two times.
The problem is that you first started at **0,0** and then ended up at **n,n**. In the second calculation you started at **n,n** and then ended up calculating backwards to **0,0**. 
So to calculate the second "slant" you have to first start at **0,n** or **n,0** and then increase the "x" coordinate and decrease the "y" coordinate" or increase the "y" coordinate and decrease the "x" coordinate.

In code this could look like this:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, am = 0, ar = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ar += arr[x][y];

    x++;
    y++;
}
x = 0;
y = arr.length - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    am += arr[x][y];

    x++;
    y--;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.